# angularjs force digest after external service request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a method from an external service, which I am using inside an angular app. This method updates some variables on the local scope (`something`).

```
$scope.something.loadServerData(callback)
```

Unfortunately, the changes are not reflected until I click a button somewhere else or generally force another digest.

Wrapping the `loadServerData()` in a `$scope.$digest()` or running it inside the callback method does not work and produces a digest already in progress error.

```
$scope.something.loadServerData(function() {
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

How can I force the UI/DOM to update and reflect the changes after the server request?

Comment: Hard to say what's happening without seeing the source of `loadServerData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your scope update inside a $timeout.
        `$timeout(fn1);`. This will trigger a digest cycle if not running already.

Or, you can try using safeApply.
https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js